# How to Find URL in a <textarea> when paragraphs and text are around URL dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I currently have a fiddle that removes URL links when pasted in. However, when there is text around the URL link, the code does not seem to work.

If possible, how can I remove the URL when there is text around it, instead of requiring to make the URL to go onto a seperate line?

Updating the fiddle would be extremely helpful, as I am new to coding.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/8/)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txtarea" placeholder="How to stop http being entered into textarea?"></textarea>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$("#txtarea").keyup(function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s*(\[\s*url\s*=\s*)?(https?:\/\/)?(www\.|\S+?\.)(\S+?\.)?\S+\s*$\s*/mg, ' ');
})
```

});

Comment: do not match the start and end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is a bit off:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/mg, ' ');
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/9/).

Comment: However, this code does not seem to be working when the URL is pasted with text surrounding the link and will only work if the link is on a seperate line. Is it possible, to remove the link when there is text around the link?

Comment: Updated the fiddle and the regex. That might be more what you're looking for. Also, please note, that matching a regular expression for a URL is an extremely challenging thing. "Valid" URL's are a very broad specification.